# How to remove line break in C# Visual Studio if-statements

Tags: c#, visual-studio, if-statement

When I type

```
if (something) { *press Enter*
```

Visual Studio automatically moves the { to the next line. I tried to disable it via config but found anything but this option.

I basically want so that this

```
if (true)
{
   int m = 3;
}
```

turns into this

```
if (true) {
   int m = 3;
}
```

How to do it?

Comment: _"I tried to disable it via config"_ - Please elaborate, because **there is** an option for that: `Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Code Style > Formatting > New Lines > Place open brace on new line for control blocks` - in `.editorconfig` it's `csharp_new_line_before_open_brace`.

Comment: While you can change this (see the answers) I would not recommend it. Almost all currently available C# code (including many public-domain libraries and the runtime itself) use the first form, so it might be worthwhile getting used to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the open brace to appear on the same line by unselecting the option "Place open brace on new line for types" in Visual Studio.

Tools > Options dialog box > Text Editor > C# > Code Style > Formatting

[image]

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/options-text-editor-csharp-formatting?view=vs-2022

Comment: This is setting does not cover what was asked in the question. The highlighted setting `Place open brace on new line for types` affects the placement of a brace on a type declaration (as shown in the screenshot); but the question was asking about the braces after an `if` condition.

Answer (score 1):

From the `Tools` menu pick `Options...`

Under `Text Editor` > `C#` > `Code Style` > `Formatting` > `New Lines`
there are lots of options which would contribute to the Kernighan & Ritchie ([K&R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#K&R_style)) bracing style. For the code in the question, the relevant setting is `Place open brace on new line for control blocks`; but you may want to change several of the others as well.

If you are using .editorconfig to manage your styling, the setting you need is [csharp_new_line_before_open_brace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/csharp-formatting-options#csharp_new_line_before_open_brace) with a value of 'none'.